# Do Not Dim Wallpaper When in Activities Overview?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, css

I would like to know if there is a way to stop the blurring of the wallpaper whenever you go into the Activities Overview in the GNOME Desktop Environment.

If so, is there a way to do it in a GNOME Shell Theme CSS file (i.e. is there a css attribute that changes the dim)?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Here's what it looks like when it's **NOT** in overview:

[image]

Here's what it looks like when it **IS** in overview:

[image]

See how the wallpaper dims?

Comment: You may have installed a gnome-shell extension that does this. Turn it off or remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GNOME Extension available at https://extensions.gnome.org that is called "Darker Overview" (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1177/darker-overview/).

The purpose of the extension is to make the dimming even DARKER (the opposite of what we are trying to do here), but if you go to the settings in the extension and make the "overview darkness" `0`, there will be no dim. Also, make sure to uncheck "show vignette" for it to completely work.

Now there will be no more dimming in the wallpaper.